# nginx dynamic change root of subdomain to folder on same level

Tags: linux, nginx

I have this hierarchy on my server:

```
/var/www/domain.tld/web
                   /sub
```

The root in the **/etc/nginx/sites-available/domain.tld** is set like this:

```
server {

  root /var/www/domain.tld/web;
  index index.html index.php index.htm; 
  ...
    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

How can I make the nginx to dynamically forward to specific folder so if I make folder in **/sub** for example /**var/www/domain.tld/sub/subdomain** so if I make request http://subdomain.domain.tld it will forward to this folder in folder sub?
So again **something.domain.tld** would be going to ***/var/www/domain.tld/sub/something*** but **domain.tld** would be going to ***/var/www/domain.tld/web***

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, welcome to StackOverflow! :)

There are probably a few ways of achieving this, but I would try a simple [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) to set a `$my_subdir` variable from the `$host`, which you can then use in your `root`.  The `$host` variable is set automatically from the incoming request.

In this example, we're using a regular expression to check if the `$host` matches *subdomain.domain.tld*.  If it does, capture the subdomain part - the bit in brackets - and use that to make the value "sub/*subdomain*" (`$1` means use the first thing captured from the regular expression).  If it doesn't match, it defaults to "web".

That way,

- when the request comes in as something like `http://domain.tld/foo.html`, the response served is `/var/www/domain.tld/web/foo.html`
- if the request comes in as something like `http://bar.domain.tld/foo.html`, the response served is `/var/www/domain.tld/sub/bar/foo.html`

```
map $host $my_subdir {
  ~^(?:www\.)?((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.domain\.tld$  sub/$1;
  default                                     web;
}

server {

  root /var/www/domain.tld/$my_subdir;
  index index.html index.php index.htm; 
  ...
    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for you reply. There is one more thing I wasn't able to figure out. Your solution works but I forgot to mention one thing. When I request url like www.sub.domain.tld or www.domain.tld I don't want them to get in the /sub/www folder. Thank's again !

Comment: No problem - see edited answer.  The regular expression is a little more complex now, but essentially it says recognise but ignore any `www.` prefix, and capture the subdomain part, making sure you don't treat `www.` on its own as a subdomain.  So now both **domain.tld** and **www.domain.tld** should map to **/web**, and **subdom.domain.tld** and **www.subdom.domain.tld** should map to **/sub/subdom**.